# Why my Javascript in html file can't display in Android WebVIew?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

The javascript code in my html file can run correctly when I use WebView.load URL to load that html file. But i want to use WebView.loadData ,then i read that html file in a String ,and use WebView.loadData. The JavaScript code in html can't run successfully. who can help me? thanks.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    try {
        InputStream is=this.getAssets().open("COPY-ME.html");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i=1;
        while ((i=is.read())!=-1) {
            baos.write(i);
        }
        data=baos.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO 自动生成的 catch 块
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

try to load your html file using below code

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/COPY-ME.html");
```

Its advised to keep your resource name in small letters.

Comment: maybe you don't read my question  carefully. the point is that i want use webView.loadData for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much,this link is very useful for me.